# Как используя регулярные выражения найти в тексте даты в заданном формате и заменить их на другой формат?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Надо используя регулярные выражения найти в тексте все даты в формате `2016-11-23` и заменяет их на формат `23.11.16`.

Было:

```
Мы изучали этот 2016-11-23
```

Стало:

```
Мы изучали этот 23.11.16
```

Вот код, который получился у меня:

```
import re

input_filename = "../progr.txt"
result_filename = "../result.txt"

input_file = open(input_filename, mode = 'r', encoding = "utf-8")
resultfile = open(result_filename, mode = 'w', encoding = "utf-8")
mytext = input_file.read()

results = re.sub(r"[\d-]", r"[\d.]", mytext)

print(results)
```

Дальше, не могу понять, как поменять даты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте [захватывающие группы (выражения в круглых скобках)](https://regex101.com/r/dBCm2p/1/):

```
s = "Мы изучали этот 2016-11-23."

results = re.sub(r"\d{2}(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})", r"\3.\2.\1", s)
# capturing groups ----> ^^^^^   ^^^^^   ^^^^^
```

результат:

```
In [6]: results
Out[6]: 'Мы изучали этот 23.11.16.'
```